# Application blocking when the target server is offline

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2019

The problem exists when the target server is offline, the application freezes for 2-3 sec, until the call is made again, where the process repeats. When the server is online, the application works correctly, is there any way to solve it?

```
private async Task<bool> StartConnect2()
{
    while (TaskIsRun)
    {
        txtConnectResult.Text += Connect2("127.0.0.1", "3333", SendRequest) + "\n";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    return false;
}
```

```
public static string Connect2(string IP, string Port, string SendData)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new(IP, int.Parse(Port));
        
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SendData);
                        
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                        
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        
        data = new byte[256];
                        
        string responseData = string.Empty;

        int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

        stream.Close();
        client.Close();

        return responseData;
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
    {
        return $"ArgumentNullException: {e.Message}\n";
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        return $"SocketException: {e.Message}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to run the connect operation on the same thread as the application's UI. If you delegate that code to a different thread, your UI should not hang anymore. This is my conclusion at first sight.

Comment: Make `Connect2` and all its network operations `async`, so you don't block you UI thread.

Comment: In addition, make sure to use `using` blocks for all objects that implement `IDisposable`. There are quite a few in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I was able to solve it using the method, "ConnectAsync" from TcpClient, I am investigating how to improve the overall performance based on your advice as well.

`
TcpClient client = new();//(IP, int.Parse(Port));
await client.ConnectAsync(IP, int.Parse(Port));
`

with this simple solution the UI does not freeze any more.